# Reverse of Deprecated / Obsolete

Tags: c#

I have a functionality in my code, but it will be available from next version. Is there any tags to notify that it is not in use, but will be available in future. I just have one way ie, [Obsolete] with custom message. Expecting other than this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember looking into replicating `[Obsolete]` for some other reason, and the answer was that it pretty much couldn't be done :( - but +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: @Rawling it can be done now.  I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

If it is not available in the current version, don't make it part of the public API. Don't expose stuff that shouldn't be used by consumers of your library.

And even when it's not a library, don't add code that you don't yet need. That violates the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle. Add the code only when it is actually needed.

Comment: But "exposing stuff that shouldn't be used by consumers of your library" is exactly what `[Obsolete]` does.

Comment: @Rawling - [Obsolete] doesn't remove the method - it's still part of the code and potentially able to be used (though it shouldn't be). What OP is wanting is basically a "Coming soon" feature. :)

Comment: @Tim That's my point. Obsolete says "I'm exposing this method but you shouldn't be using it". So to say "don't try to make a 'coming soon' attribute as you shouldn't expose a method that people shouldn't use" is inconsistent with that.

Comment: @Rawling - Its semantics, but to me Obsolete means something entirely different than coming soon.  Anyway, the overall point (from my point of view) is that OP shouldn't have functionality in their code that they don't want the consumer to use until the next version. *shrug*  Not a hill to die on :)

Comment: Rawling: [Obsolete] means: "We're sorry we've ever exposed this feature, but we can't remove it because of backwards compatibility.". That's something completely different than: "Here's a new feature, but please don't use it yet.". This increases the [WTFs/m](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

Comment: Still I'm not clear with the situation. Where should I keep the implemented functionality? Where should I put the efforts?

Comment: There are a lot of places where you can keep that code, as long as you don't make the API public. Make it internal or wrap with #if DEBUG directives or store it in the mail, on disk, what ever. What ever you do, don't ship it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create throw a CustomError message from that method saying "This method is not available for the current version. It is for future" something like that.

Or else you can make the method as Obselete and specify the reason in the message.
[Obsolete("I have written this method for future use. Do not use it in the current version.")]

Comment: OP stated in their question that they know they can do it that way, but was looking for alternatives.

Comment: OP made no mention of throwing an exception. I like and use this during development to protect me from the stub code I neglected to finish :-/


I know - that's a different topic. Still I think Sreejith's post is helpful/

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your question, I assume you want to generate a compiler warning when someone attempts to call this method, stating that it has not yet been implemented.

`ObsoleteAttribute` is hard coded into the C# compiler as something that should generate a warning message. Therefore there is no way to mark a method as 'to be implemented in the future' without modifying the compiler itself.

From the C# Spec:

> The attribute Obsolete is used to mark types and members of types that
>   should no longer be used.
>        If a program uses a type or member that is decorated with the Obsolete attribute, the compiler issues a warning or an error.
>   Specifically, the compiler issues a warning if no error parameter is
>   provided, or if the error parameter is provided and has the value
>   false. The compiler issues an error if the error parameter is
>   specified and has the value true.

I suggest to not expose methods that are not yet implemented, since it makes no sense to use them. If this is part of a team development effort, specifying API contracts before developing specific modules, you should consider throwing a `NotImplementedException` or provide a dummy implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this question as there is now a real solution thanks to [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn): Code analyzers.

Just add [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompilerAttributes/) to your project and you'll be able to create attributes that will be picked up by the compiler!

The [GitHub repo readme](https://github.com/gregsdennis/CompilerAttributes) has the instructions, and it's really simple.